# How to set target net7.0 -windows?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2022

I try change

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

to

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

but build error. How to set target to `net7.0-windows` success?

[image]

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   NETSDK1045  The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET 7.0.  Either target .NET 6.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET 7.0.    acore   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.201\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets   144
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
C:\Users\donhu>dotnet --info
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   7.0.100-preview.2.22153.17
 Commit:    9c52c56c13

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.22000
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.100-preview.2.22153.17\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 7.0.0-preview.2.22152.2
  Commit:  e24f66dff0

.NET SDKs installed:
  6.0.201 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  7.0.100-preview.2.22153.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.23 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.0-preview.2.22153.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.23 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.0-preview.2.22152.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.23 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 7.0.0-preview.2.22153.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

To install additional .NET runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

C:\Users\donhu>
```

Related: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/visual-studio-multi-targeting-overview?view=vs-2022

Comment: Well, that suggests you don't have the .NET 7.0 SDK installed - or that you've got a global.json file forcing the 6.0 SDK.

Comment: I have .NET 7 preview installed. Its maybe cause by .NET 7 preview installer bug/error/mistake.

Comment: I guess you need Vistual Studio 2022 preview edition

Comment: I also look for Visual Studio 2022 preview edition, but I am not found. Can you help me find download link?

Comment: In the Visual Studio installer, you need to change which release channel you're using, via More -> Update Settings.

Comment: What does your `global.json` say? You need to have an SDK version selected that's _at least_ the version of the target runtime.

Comment: Please guide me where and how get information of `global.json` (I moved from Java to .NET, I don't know much)

Comment: You can download Visual Studio 2022 preview from [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/zh-hans/vs/preview/)

Comment: I see "Comes with .NET 6" , I don't think it support .NET 7, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thank to Maytham (propose me about Visual Studio 2022 preview) and Jon Skeet (about how to get Visual Studio 2022 preview, it is different with Visual Studio 2019 preview downloading).

Solution: In Visual Studio 2022, choose Preview channel. Then update to VS 2022 preview, then we can choose Target framework .NET 7.0 easily.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to do this with VS2022 17.4.3 ?  .Net 7.0 SDK is installed but the dropdown still does not display it.  I know it's a Microsoft bug, but until they fix it, developing in .Net 7.0 is not possible (as of Dec 26 2022)!

Comment: @mc9000 I have the same error. Have you found any solution ?

Comment: I ended up reinstalling VS, then it worked. Using 17.4.5 version. Go figure.

Comment: Where is this screenshot from? I don't have such interface and such options in my visual studio

Comment: @Espeon Visual Studio has been changed this User Interface. You cannot see it now. At this time, Visual Studio Preview setup will like the old one of 2020 year.

Answer (score 16):

No need to install VS Preview at all. Go to "Options -> Preview Features" and enable the "Use previews of the .NET SDK (requires restart): option.

[image: 1]